# Jquery Accordion with icons

Tags: jquery, accordion

I use a simple jquery accordion from page https://www.mediaevent.de/javascript/lib-jquery-Plugins.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#drawers').find('h5').click(function(){
$(this).next().slideToggle();
$("#drawers div").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
});
</script>
```

The HTML

```
<ul id="drawers">
<li>
  <h5>Item 1</h5>
  <div class="first">AAAA</div>
</li>
…
<li>
  <h5>Item 2</h5>
  <div>BBBB</div>
</li>
```

And the CSS

```
#drawers div { display:none; }
#drawers div.first { display:block; }
```

Now I need a hint for adding two diffent icons of Font Awesome for a open and a closed accordion in front of the `<h5>`.

Comment: Inside your click function, just toggle the class associated with the fa-icon you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not an experienced jquery user. Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: I left an answer, along with a jsfiddle that should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your click function, use `toggleClass()` associated with the fa-icon you want to use. I put together a quick fiddle for you. https://jsfiddle.net/av17nkbk/2/

```
<script>
   $('#drawers').find('h5').click(function(){
       $(this).next().slideToggle();
       $(this).find('i.fa').toggleClass('fa-caret-down fa-caret-up');
       $("#drawers div").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
        });
</script>
```

`<ul id="drawers">
<li>
  <h5><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>Item 1</h5>
  <div class="first">AAAA</div>
</li>`

Comment: Thanks a lot, The solution is nearly perfect. Only one problem remains: After calling up the website the first item is open, while all the other items are closed. So the first item needs another icon than the other ones. Is that possible?

Comment: Of course, just place whatever icon you want in the starting html, the jquery will automatically toggle it for you. I can edit the fiddle if that helps.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it. Could you please accept my answer as correct?

Comment: I'm happy to accept your answer. :-) But there is one more problem unfortunately. I could solve the problem with two different icons in the beginning. When I click now on an item the first item will be closed automatically without a 'direct' click and so the icon for the first item will not change and is wrong for a closed item. So all the items get more and more wrong. Hope I could explain the problem. –

Comment: Maybe it's helpful to know, that jquery adds style="display: none;" to div when the item ist closed and style="display: block;" for the open item.

Comment: A nice solution could be that an item isn't closed automaticaly when another ist opened.

Comment: I will look into it further on Monday if you are still having issues.

Comment: I could solve the problem in a different way. Thanks for your help.